# set a dataset by dereferencing a variable

Tags: sas

I would like to set a dataset by using a reference to dataset name however Iam getting error message: ERROR: File dataset_name123  does not exist(work.dataset123 does exist) What is wrong?

```
data _null_;
%let product = 'dataset_name123';
set work.&product nobs = row_no;
put row_no;
put &product;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member names are not quoted.  Remove the quotes from your macro variable.  In macro code everything is character so there is no need to add quotes around string literals.  The quotes become part of the value of the macro variable.

```
%let product = dataset_name123;
%put &=product;

data _null_;
  set work.&product nobs = row_no;
  put row_no;
  put "&product";
  stop;
run;
```

If you do include quotes in a dataset reference then SAS will interpret it as the physical name of the dataset file itself.  So code like:

```
data want;
  set 'dataset_name123';
run;
```

would look for a filename 'dataset_name123.sas7bdat' in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a great idea to do a %let statement in a data step. Macrovariables and SAS variables are created differently.
 There are two problems in this code. First one is quotes around macrovariable, which after resolution will be used for table name and hence your query fails as table names cannot be in quotes .
second one is put statement for macro variable  for macro variable to resolve you need %put.

below is modified code.

```
 data class;
 set sashelp.class;
 run;

 data _null_;
%let product = class;
set work.&product nobs = row_no;
put row_no;
%put &product;
run;
```